# CSS trouble with IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I am designing a website and it looks good in basically all browsers except IE7, where I have a problem I haven't been able to correct. I have a menu in HTML like this:

```
<div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li id="cMenu"><a id="cart" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li id="pMenu"><a id="promos" href="#">Promos</a></li>
            <li id="aMenu"><a id="anun" href="#">Ads</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /nav -->
```

Then I have my CSS:

```
div#nav{width:339px;height:120px;display:block;}

div#nav ul{list-style:none;}
div#nav ul li{display:inline;padding:20px;}
div#nav ul li a{width:30px;height:80px;}

div#nav ul li#cMenu{text-indent:-999999px;}
div#nav ul li a#cart{background:url(../img/menu2.png) 0 50px no-repeat;width:110px;height:120px;display:block;}
div#nav ul li a#cart:hover{background:url(../img/menu2.png) 0 -69px no-repeat;}
```

The thing here is that when I preview this on IE7 nothing gets displayed, I've tired positioning absolutely and also checking if everything is there by using border="dotted" and I get to see the border of only the div#nav, nothing else shows up. (I didn't placed all of the css of the menu since it's basically the same just different id's).

Does anybody knows what's wrong?

Comment: Are you using a doctype, and have you tried `display: block;` for the `li` elements (to make sure they're being rendered)? Also make sure you've closed any/all `script` and `style` tags in the document's `<head>`.

Comment: yes, I am using <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> and it validates. I've checked all the tags and they're closed as for the display:block I hadn't tried it, but when I did, it appeared, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`display: block;`

for your CSS nav declaration. That should fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

div#nav ul li#cMenu{text-indent:-999999px;}

by this its sending all inside li  tag to -9999999 text-indent

try putting text-indent to **a** tag

i hope it work